# Are CPU and RAM modules of a laptop reusable to upgrade another laptop?

Tags: laptop, motherboard

The motherboard of my Huawei Matebook Pro is broken. Considering the replacement cost was so high I asked the repair person to at least detach the CPU and RAM modules so I could use them on my older laptop. However, he has sent me the motherboard. You can see its image here.
https://images.sellbrite.com/production/18202/BB8310186X000128/d5f800e8-062e-57bf-9650-d47f8a28304b.jpg

It does not seem that I can easily detach anything from it and use it on something else. Is it true? When it was working it was an expensive piece of technology. does it have any value now?!

Comment: I don't think one really needs an expensive laptop these days.. also don't get a laptop where you haven't seen a video on changing the hard drive and RAM (To make sure that it opens easily and that the RAM isn't soldered on like they are with your one!), otherwise if the RAM is soldered on it's not upgradable.

Comment: The only thing I see is a soldered CPU and since the screenshot isn’t detailed enough I am going to guess soldered memory. “Huawei Matebook Pro” isn’t detailed enough description to do any research

Comment: Laptops CPUs have been soldered for ~10 years now

Comment: @gronostaj what about rams?

Comment: @HandsomeNerd Others have answered that well: it varies by model.

Answer (score 3):

Most laptops do not have detachable processors, and many modern machines also have soldered on RAM.

In particular more portable machines are more likely to have everything soldered. It being expensive means nothing, thinner machines have far less room for things like DIMM and CPU connectors and so are more likely to have nothing that can be taken off.

There is nothing usable by anyone without specialised soldering equipment on that board.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this unit is not user repairable, and it is not cost effective to salvage parts as they have been soldered onto the motherboard - it likely has very little to no value - indeed there are places which will charge you to take it off your hands.